# How to access api.hypixel.net using Python

Tags: python, api, api-design

I am relatively well versed in basic python programming, but I have never learned how to access an API. I just would like to learn how to first access api.hypixel.net and then learn how I would go about accessing anything in this API. I have tried to learn it through previous stack overflow posts and through the internet, but I have not been able to fully understand how to access a specific and unique API. Thanks in advance, and I'm sorry if this is super easy, but I am very new to APIs in Python.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't see any kind of API documentation for their API. Most likely it's HTTP API. So first thing you need is `requests` library. You can read the source code of their library https://github.com/HypixelDev/PublicAPI/blob/master/Java/src/main/java/net/hypixel/api/HypixelAPI.java#L232 to get more insights about API endpoints

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry that I forgot to show where the documentation was. If you pressed "Github Repost," it would've led you to this GitHub https://github.com/HypixelDev/PublicAPI/tree/master/Documentation. If you wouldn't mind checking this it would be greatly appreciated. Thanks again for your time and consideration.

Comment: Yea I have checked that as well, but the documentation is very poor. It doesn't have description of how to call API, how to add API key and so on. So the source of truth for you is that java source code file I've linked above.

Comment: So it has base url and you should append different things to that base url. And make queries with python and `requests` library. Do you know how to obtain API key?

Comment: I am not sure how to obtain the specific API key, but I will search through the documentation that you linked above, thank you a lot and I will see what I can do for now.